# How to create global variable in .tpl file in PrestaShop?

Tags: php, html, css, prestashop-1.7

I would like to create a global variable, which will be set and get in `.tpl` file. The global variable should be saved for the user (logged in or not)

Answer (score 0):

Created an override in `Override -> classes -> controller -> FrontController.php`

And add code :

```
<?php

use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Cart\CartPresenter;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\ObjectPresenter;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Configuration as ConfigurationAdapter;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Image\ImageRetriever;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'VARIABLE_NAME' => VARIABLE_VALUE,
        ));
        return parent::initContent();
    }
}
?>
```